# Character checking not working

Tags: javascript, java

Currently I'm trying to create a very simple code that can simply just play a strategy game. There is an issue however; I can't seem to get the character comparison to work. Some help please?

```
 while (nameTwo == "1")
```

that is my loop checking for if it is the number one in a string, then execute but it is not being read. Any help?

Comment: java or javascript? also, give us a little bit more code. The above is either an infinite loop or doesn't loop at all unless you modify nameTwo inside the loop body.

Comment: your question is ambiguous. do you want character comparison or string comparison?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 0):

```
    I think you're looking for this

     while (nameTwo.equals("1"))
```